# Why is the pronunciation of the O in "move" different from in "bone"?

Tags: pronunciation

I have read about the silent "e" rule. So, in the word "bone", it seems to work with "o" having its letter sound. But, we say "move" as in "moov". Why this difference? Is it historical or due to some rule?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the **O** followed by **V**.  Compare _glove, above, dove (bird), love, shove_.    It also seems to affect **I** followed by **V**:  give, live (verb)_ and any word with the suffix _-ive_.

Comment: I forgot to mention _prove_, which is more to the point. And yes, I realize thus is no answer; that's why I put it in Comments.

Comment: There is some useful discussion here: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e   (look under the heading **Truly silent e**)  Unfortunately it does not specifically mention "move " or "prove", but it does mention a historical change from *f* to *v* in some of the words that turned out to be exceptions.

Comment: And "love"? (It won't take my comment without more words.)

Comment: Perhaps another no-rule rule, like, though through rough cough bough [which itself has a surname variant pronounced 'boff', agreeing with some pronunciations of sough]

Comment: *Move* is of Latin origin and *bone* is of Germanic/Anglo-Saxon origin. The 'v' in *move* colors the 'o' vowel bringing it forwards towards the lips; the 'n' of 'bone' keeps the 'o' more open and central.

Comment: @TRomano - not that I doubt you're right, but I'm not sure of *why* that should make the pronunciation as it is. We have the 'opposite' pronunciations for both words, in mauve & boon.

Comment: 1.  'mauve' is Latin *malva*.  The open back vowel /a/ represented by the first 'a' in *malva*  and /u/ are at opposite ends of the open-closed continuum, whereas the /o/ of *movere* is quite near /u/ on that continuum.  /o/ can be drawn towards /u/ far more easily than /a/ can under the influence of sounds that follow after it, such as the labio-dental /v/.  2. With 'boon', it isn't the /n/ that causes the /o/ to become /u/. Rather, during the Great Vowel Shift, the long back vowel in OE *bān* /a/ becomes /o/ and the long back vowel in Norse-loan-word *bón* /o/  becomes /u/.

Comment: "move" is from Old French "movoir". That yielded Modern French "mouvoir" (with a /u/ like English). And "prove" is from Old French "prover/pruver" which also yielded Modern French "prouver" (again, also with a /u/ as in English). Both Old French words came from Latin words with /o/ in them. If this sound change can be explained, we've got our answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that there's no rule (like the silent E is a rule).

I recommend thinking of *move* as being some sort of exception.

Answer (score 0):

One of the curious exceptions to the "silent e" rule is essentially a matter of syntax. In general, English words do not end with the letter "v" or "u", and the presence of the "e" is merely a reconciliation of that fact without affecting the pronunciation of the intervening vowel.

Comment: True, but unfotunately it does not explain why _move_  and _prove_ rhyme with _groove_ rather than with _love, glove, dove, shove_.

Comment: @Brian - Because that's the way English goes? We could also talk about these pairs of words, which also seem like they would rhyme: _blood & hood, down & own, hearth and earth_. But I think David has a good point about "v" being a particularly vexing letter when it comes to silent e's: (consider _have & save_, and _give & dive_).

Comment: J.R. Yeah, I know that's just how English goes, but it's somehow unsatisfying to give only that as an answer.  I have seen that answer sugar-coated as  "you really have to observe how native speakers {pronounce/punctuate/arrange words/use this idiom/whatever}, but it still sounds like a cop-out.  Oh, and incidentally, David, how is adding a dummy E after V or U "a matter of syntax"?

Answer (score 0):

English spelling is rarely based upon true phonetics, but rather upon word roots and etymology. The disjointed pronunciation and spelling of the word "move" in comparison to its similarly suffixed counterparts is likely due to such factors.

[The online etymology dictionary](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=move&allowed_in_frame=0) suggests a French influence for the word, with possible provenance reaching as far back as Indo-European roots, which both have spelling construction that hint at the modern pronunciation in English, whereas the Latin root of the French word informs its current English orthography. It is notable that the French root from which English inherits its spelling has been modified in Modern French and provides better phonetic guidance to today's French reader, unlike English.

> late 13c., from Anglo-French mover, Old French movoir "to move, get moving, set out; set in motion; introduce" (Modern French mouvoir), from Latin movere "move, set in motion; remove; disturb" (past participle motus, frequentative motare), from PIE root *meue- "to push away" (cognates: Sanskrit kama-muta "moved by love" and probably mivati "pushes, moves;" Lithuanian mauti "push on;" Greek ameusasthai "to surpass," amyno "push away").

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the Great Vowel Shift between 1350-1700's. Many of the words we commonly use have changed pronunciation while keeping the spelling.

SPELLING
The spelling of "move" was of course based on the Latin movere: mov(e) - movie, movable etc.
The "e" is there because English words don't end in v (or u).

PRONUNCIATION (using IPA and simple diacritic)
So many words were changed in pronunciation during the Great Vowel Shift (see [PHY117 - The Great Vowel Shift by Prof. Jürgen Handke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyhZ8NQOZeo) 6:32).
In stage 2 of the Shift [o:] changed to to [u:]. He uses the example of "food" previously pronounced [fo:d] or /fŏd/ (or a sound between /ŏ/ and /ä/) and shifted to [fu:d] or /food/.

So - "move" would have been pronounced by its spelling [mo:v] then shifted to [mu:v] ( /mŏv/ to /moov/ ).

Other explanations of pronunciation is the spelling indicated the pronunciation differently to today - "blood" for example has double 'o' to indicate a long o /ō/ instead of the "magic e" - /b-l-ō-d/ NOT /b-l-oo-d/. Then the Great Vowel Shift changed many of the pronunciations from /ō/ to /ŭ/. (as opposed to "flood" which derived from the German Flut /floot/, which changed pronunciation possibly due to the same reason for how it was spelled -  from /oo/ to be read as /ō/ and then had the same change from /ō/ to /ŭ/). So it's almost like they found a middle ground for the sound.

Remember that the pronunciation of vowels can be changed significantly due to the letters that come before and after as they distort the sound, especially using a schwa due to lesser significance in a sentence. So even if you think you pronounce a pure vowel sound, it may actually sound like another in the area of the mouth too, and not lose meaning within the sentence. It could even be due to class - if an English person from say South London says "move" they may actually be saying /mōv/ and be correct due to accent, while if a North American or Australian said it that way, it would be mispronunciation.

Comment: Middle English /o:/ is only one possible source of Modern English /u:/. Modern English /u:/ can also come from Middle English /u:/ before a labial consonant such as *p, m,* or *v.* So it's not actually clear that "move" used to have /o:/. Do you have a source that describes this? I found in the Oxford English Dictionary just a note "The origin of the modern English vowel quality has been variously explained. For a summary and a further explanation see B. Diensberg Anglo-French Loanwords & Middle Eng. Lengthening in Open Syllables in M. Markus Historical Eng. (1988) 146–50."